# Load Dataframe in Apache Spark parallelly

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to create 2 dataframe, both has different set of data. I want to load both the CSV parallel.

Algo:

1. Load X Dataframe, perform opertations to build a aggregated view and tranform into Y Dataframe
2. Load Z Dataframe, and join it with Y Dataframe.

Since I am performing about 30min job in step #1, i will like to parrellely load Z, so that by the time Y is ready, I can move on to join and rest of the operations.

How can i do it optimally?

One of the way i can think of is using threads, but it is the best?

```
        // Use threads for parallelization
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read()
                    .option("multiLine", true)  // Handle multiline CSV records (if applicable)
                    .csv(folder1Path);
            // Perform necessary transformations on df1 here
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read()
                    .option("multiLine", true)  // Handle multiline CSV records (if applicable)
                    .csv(folder2Path);
            // Perform necessary transformations on df2 here
        });

        // Start threads concurrently
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        // Wait for threads to finish
        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
// Load X Dataframe and perform necessary operations to build aggregated view
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read()
        .option("multiLine", true)  // Handle multiline CSV records (if applicable)
        .csv(folder1Path);

// Perform necessary transformations on df1 here

// Load Z Dataframe in parallel
Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read()
        .option("multiLine", true)  // Handle multiline CSV records (if applicable)
        .csv(folder2Path);

// Join df2 with df1 (Y Dataframe)
Dataset<Row> result = df1.join(df2, /* join condition */, "inner");

// Further operations on the result dataframe

// Perform an action to trigger the execution of the Spark job
result.show();
```

Apache Spark operations are evaluated lazily, which means that computation occurs only when an action is called. Spark attempts to optimize operations by default, including parallelization where possible. Therefore, there is no need to explicitly manage threads for parallelization within Spark.

Comment: Is union better than Join? since i plan to union them instead of join..

Comment: It's hard to say which is better. If your goal is to simply stack rows from two datasets on top of each other, not based on common keys, union is the way to go. On the other hand, if you need to combine datasets based on certain conditions or keys, then join is good.